# Quickly validate columns of web links in pandas dataframe with multiple links in a single field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests, urllib

FIRST: This is sort of a duplicate, as there are solutions dating back to pre-2014 for the link validation. What I am trying to do is look for a modern solution that is quick. Basically combining several of the standard answers, as well as ensuring there aren't newer better options.

I have a dataframe with ~10 columns, and 100k rows. The first column (ID) can be ignored, the rest of the columns are hit or miss if they have anything in them. I only care if the links are good. (These *should* all be image url's, and I don't need any of the data on the other side. - so I was just looking for a 200 response. But I'm not sure if that's the best way either.) ***Some fields can contain multiple delimited links (delimiter: ~|~) - this is a bit of a wrench I don't know how to solve at all***

I had originally thought to just check general structure of the URL's and create a df that listed out the ID and any columns that had improperly formatted url's. I found multiple solutions utilizing regex, urlparse, or the validators package.

But then I thought, what does it matter if it's formatted correctly. I really need to know if it's valid.  That's where I found multiple solutions involving requests and urllib.

After trying a few implementations, I think I have something that works overall. But it's not quick, and I'm not sure how to apply it across the whole df.

I used the requests implementation and added a try/except piece to handle invalid url's and create a 2in1 solution for formatting/connection detection.

```
url_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,5,25,26],
    'link1':['apple', 'www.google.com', 'gm@yahoo.com', 'http://www.youtube.com', '888-555-5556 Ryan Parkes rp@abc.io'],
    'link2':['http://www.bing.com','http://www.linkedin.com','',' please call now','http://www.reddit.com' ],
    'link3':['http://www.stackoverflow.com~|~http://www.ebay.com', 'http://www.imdb.com', 'http://www.google.co.uk','more random text that could be really long and annoying','over the hills and through the woods']
    })

def url_exists(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:  #should I be looking for something other than just 200?
        return True
    else:
        return False


for col in url_df.columns:
    for i in url_df[col]:
        try:
            url_exists(i)
        except:
            print('Invalid URL', i)
            continue
```

Ultimately the response I want to get to is something like:

```
url_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,2,5,25,26],
    'link1':['Invalid', 'Invalid', 'Invalid', 'Good', 'Invalid'],
    'link2':['Good','Good','Invalid','Invalid','Good' ],
    'link3':['ERROR', 'Good', 'Broken','Invalid','Invalid']
    })
```

**NOTE** -  the uk.google is actually a broken link for me due to my VPN.

For the delimited links, I don't know what to do.  Possibly try to find fields like that and then break the links apart individually to evaluate, and then return a Good/Broken/Invalid indicator if any fail?

But the real crux of my question is how do you possibly parallelize this to make it quick and apply to the entire dataframe?